# PHP RegExp certain chars

Tags: php, regex

What would be a good way to get rid of all chars except, letters, numbers, double quotes and hyphens. This is what I got so far.

```
$test = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9"-]#',' ',$string);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Your approach is fine, and pretty standard so any developer would understand.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use the solution you already have?

Comment: was just wondering if for some reason there was a possible mistake. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is about as good a solution as you are going to find.

Answer (score 2):

You can use \d to match digits, and the flag i to match a-z with case insensitivity.

```
$test = preg_replace('#[^a-z\d\w"-]#i','',$string);
```

Here is the php regex-syntax reference: http://se.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php